# Query a polyline layer using arcGIS's Javascript API

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, query-layer

I'm attempting to query a polyline layer using the ArcGIS Javascript API I all ready have a lot of experience doing this with Point layers. So I set my Polyline layer up the same way and stopped and started my service again to get every thing going. When I run the query (specifically when I run PolylineQueryTask.execute()) I get an error that just says the operation can't be completed. There is some code below that shows how I'm setting my query layer up. Any ideas on what I can do to fix this issue or things I should try?

```
PolylineQueryTask = new esri.tasks.QueryTask("http://" + DomainAddress + "/ArcGIS/rest/services/SNND/MapServer/1");

PolylineQuery = new esri.tasks.Query();
PolylineQuery.returnGeometry = true;
PolylineQuery.outFields = ["ObjID"];

PolylineQuery.where = 'where 1 = 1';
PolylineQueryTask.execute(PolylineQuery, ShowPolylineResults, FatlError);
```

So  as you can see from my code I should be getting all my polylines back. Any thoughts are very appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found my problem and I feel like a complete moron for my screw up seeing as how I've used this function so many times before.

```
PolylineQuery.where = 'where 1 = 1';
```

the above line should be

```
PolylineQuery.where = '1 = 1';
```

I don't need to specify the word 'where'

I'm an idiot :)

Comment: Upvote for himself 'idiot' epiphany.